# Angular find via attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have problem with my script.

js

```
   $scope.showConfirm = function(e) {
     var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
       title: 'some title',
       template: 'ccccccc'
     });
     confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
       if(res) {
          var a = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("div['data-id'="+e+"]"));
          console.log(a);
       }
     });
   };
```

and html:

```
<div class="green" data-id="{{mydiv.mydiv_id}}">
<p>some text </p>

    <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="showConfirm({{mydiv.mydiv_id}})">
      Wykonane
    </button>
  </div>
```

Everything works well, id is allocated and when I check the console that also is all okay, but at this stage need to click the button changed class.For example when I'm click "showConfirm()" I need change class in div where data-id = showConfirm(id).
Now my div have class green, when I' click button this class change to red. In jquery the same script view like this:

```
$(button).on(click, function(e){
 var element = $("div[data-id="+e+"]");
element.removeClass(green);
element.addClass(red)
});
```

How to do it?

EDIT:

I see that I need to add full code to make it clear :)

updated code:

```
   $scope.showConfirm = function(e) {
     var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
       title: 'title',
       template: 'eeeeee'
     });
     confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
       if(res) {
          var a = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("div['data-id'="+e+"]"));
          console.log(a);
          $http.get("http://example/rest_api/json?id="+e)
            .success(function(data){
              // if success set green
            })
            .error(function(){
              // if error set red
            })
       }
     });
   };
```

I need change class when my server is success response.

Comment: Wow :o 3 anwsers on 4 min :o I must test it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `ng-class` instead of `class`.
For example

You could also do this using objects, and based on your edit it could be something like:

Updating the HTML

```
<div data-id="{{mydiv.mydiv_id}}" ng-class="conditions[mydiv.mydiv_id] ? 'green' : 'red'">
```

And in your controller `$scope.conditions = {};` and just set it to `true` or `false` in your `success` and `error` like : `$scope.conditions[e] = true /* or false */;`

Note. If you want the default to be green just set the condition to `true` on init or do the validations and settings assuming the expected to be a negative value.

Comment: You could update your condition inside your callback. I'll provide an updated  answer

Comment: @bradley546994 this also allows you to have multiple items.

Answer (score 3):

You should do everything in angular way. angular.element is not the right solution.

You can use ng-class of angular.

Example

```
<i class="fa" ng-class="{'class-name1': condition1 == 'true', 'class-2': condition2== 'true'}"></i>
```

if condition 1 is true then class-name1 will be added, if condtion2 is true then class-2 class will be added.

HTML

```
<div ng-class="{'green': buttonClicked == true, 'red': responseInYes== true}">

$scope.showConfirm = function(e) {
     $scope.buttonClicked = true;
     $scope.responseInYes= false;

 var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
   title: 'some title',
   template: 'ccccccc'
 });
 confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
   if(res) {
          $scope.buttonClicked = false;
          $scope.responseInYes= true;

   }
 });
```

};

I guess you are looking for something like this.

Comment: Modified answer. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-class

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes to be added.

Check [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) out.

In your case i suggest to do :

```
$scope.isGreen = false; 
$http.get("http://example/rest_api/json?id="+e)
        .success(function(data){
          $scope.isGreen = true;
        })
        .error(function(){ 
        })
```

In your Html file add this:

```
ng-class="{'class-green': isGreen, 'class-red': !isGreen}"
```

Comment: It works but when I have multiple object for example ng-repeat all of object has class green.what I could do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating a property inside `mydiv`:

```
<div class="{{mydiv._class}}">
    <p>some text </p>
    <button class="button button-primary" ng-click="showConfirm(mydiv)">
        Wykonane
    </button>
</div>
```

Then, in your function:

```
$scope.showConfirm = function(e) {
    // your popup window and some more code ...

    e._class = 'yellow'; // class for fecthing data (waiting server json result)

    $http.get(URL).success(function(data) {
        e._class = 'green'; // class for success
    }).error(function() {
        e._class = 'red'; // class for error
    });
};
```

Comment: @bradley546994. Does it fit your needs this way?

Comment: The main idea here is to maintain the MVC aspect: 1. The view `{{mydiv._class}}` will live in your HTML template 2. The controller will rule how and when to set the `_class` model-property from your javascript file.